# On conversion from NSString to NSData

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdata

Let's say I have some string as such:

```
NSString *someString = @"123";
```

Then, I convert this string to an instance of NSData as such:

```
NSData *someData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[someString UTF8String] length:[someString length]];
```

As far as I understand, NSData is essentially just an encoding-less stream of bits. My question is: does NSData determine how many bits are in each UTF8String by checking the value for the length parameter? In other words, [someString UTF8String] returns a C string containing the characters "123", and [someString length] returns the integer 3. Does NSData understand that each character then must consist of 8 bits? Am I totally missing the point?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

```
+ (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length
```

This method takes simply 2 parameters: void pointer to byte stream in memory and length in the terms how many should be taken into NSData object from this byte stream. This method, as any other, doesn't have a clue and doesn't care, how you got this byte stream and certainly doesn't know anything about UTF8String, it cares only about data types, that they match method signature.

Your idea about how to determine the length of the string is also wrong as Matthias explained. Use strlen C function for that. This function checks upon string termination null character \0.

Comment: Yea I see now. Thanks for clearing that up. I've been an iOS developer for about 5 years now, I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't know the distinction. :X EDIT: Ah, I see why I was confused now - this whole time I was under the impression that it was BITS, not bytes (for the first parameter) - all makes sense now, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

`length` returns the length of the string, as in "The number of Unicode characters", it does not return the number of bytes in its backing store.

To convert a NSString to NSData you have to use something like this:

```
NSString *someString = @"123";
NSData *someData = [someString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

What you do, works for UTF8 that only contains ASCII, because even in UTF8 the ASCII characters takes up only 1 byte. Coincidentally the "logical" length of the string matches the size of its backing store.

Try with a string that contains characters outside of the ASCII range and you will see different results:

```
NSString *asciiString = @"123";
NSLog(@"\"%@\" - Length: %ld", asciiString, (long)[asciiString length]);
NSData *asciiData = [asciiString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data length: %ld", [asciiData length]);

NSString *utf8String = @"";
NSLog(@"\"%@\" - Length: %ld", utf8String, (long)[utf8String length]);
NSData *utf8Data = [utf8String dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data length: %ld", [utf8Data length]);

utf8String = @"oö";
NSLog(@"\"%@\" - Length: %ld", utf8String, (long)[utf8String length]);
utf8Data = [utf8String dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Data length: %ld", [utf8Data length]);
```

Yields:

```
"123" - Length: 3
Data length: 3
"" - Length: 2
Data length: 4
"oö" - Length: 2
Data length: 3
```

Comment: Did you read any of what I wrote? Lol - Please reread and then answer my question. P.S. - dataWithBytes:length: works just fine for converting NSString to NSData. Your code and my code yield the same result. - Also, did not mean to come off with a harsh tone.

Comment: then try with a string that does not only contain ASCII

Comment: Ah. I see. Good point. Still though, could you address my question?